# Strange problem enabling transmission as boot daemon [Rasp B with ArchLinux]

Tags: networking, boot, services

again me :)
I installed ArchLinux on my rasp B. After that, I installed transmission. I set the settings.json in a way that I can access it through the webgui. 
I can see the webgui when I go to //rasp_ip:9091.
Now I wanted to start transmission automatically and if I give this command (as said in the doc https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Daemon):

```
systemctl enable transmission
```

He starts at boot but accessing it through website he gives me the classic transmission error:

```
403: Forbidden. Unauthorized IP Address. ecc.
```

If I disable the autostart, reboot the rasp and launch manually the daemon, I can access it through website... It's like it's changing the settings.json file, is it possible? How can I solve it? Thank you all very much

UPDATE:
Tried to give

```
ps aux | grep transmission
```

And I get

```
transmi+   114  0.1  0.5  25096  2396 ?        Ssl  19:07   0:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
root       288  0.0  0.2   4080   952 pts/0    S+   19:14   0:00 grep transmission
```

I give this anyway after obviously stopped the daemon

```
nano ~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

and I have this whitelist option

```
"rpc-enabled": true,
"rpc-password": "{3c060ff110366902b432b1c28c39dc714bba20e2LKR8ZSqD",
"rpc-port": 9091,
"rpc-url": "/transmission/",
"rpc-username": "",
"rpc-whitelist": "",
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,
```

again it doesn't function.

UPDATE 2:

I noticed that giving

```
ps aux | grep transmission
```

when I stopped the daemon and re-started it manually giving

```
transmission-daemon
```

I receive

```
root       277  4.5  0.4  26120  2324 ?        Ssl  19:51   0:00 transmission-daemon
root       285  0.0  0.2   4076   948 pts/0    S+   19:51   0:00 grep transmission
```

So what's transmi+ ?

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the italian documentation page about transmission. Reading the english version I found the chapter: "Choosing a user"
It says

```
Choose how you want to run transmission:
- As a separate user, transmission by default (recommended for increased security).
By default, transmission creates a user and a group transmission, with its home files at /var/lib/transmission/
```

So I gave

```
nano /var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

and I set the file :)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Transmission